# My CentOS 7 won't boot anymore

Tags: centos, boot, partition, dracut

My CentOS 7 won't boot anymore. I returns by after boot:

> Assuming drive cache: write through

I found some things to remove rhgb via the boot menu, but that didn't work. I remove it, and saved it with ctrl+x, but still won't boot.

There is probably some partition table gone missing. 
I don't know what happend, because it was a long time I rebooted the machine. I'm debugging it the whole afternoon now with Google, but still have no solution. Someone that can help out?

[image: consoleoutput]

Answer (score 1):

The red errors are red herrings (they would happen anyway).  You have a working /boot but you're failing to activate the LVM partition (probably sda2).

The unknown partition table... I grant it's suspicious.  But you probably installed with both /boot and LVM on the same disk, sda.  In which case you're already having problems with sda...

```
file -s /dev/sda1

file -s /dev/sda2
```

will describe the partitions e.g.

```
/dev/sda3: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: 8OtrnK-xreK-CyDK-Jdcq-VayD-tbUG-tycS0L, size: 119645667328
```

EDIT: except the initramfs probably doesn't have file!  Try `blkid` instead though, because I think that's what udev uses.

```
/dev/sda3: UUID="8OtrnK-xreK-CyDK-Jdcq-VayD-tbUG-tycS0L" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="82bcd2d1-39af-436f-9b58-4ec8434483a2"
```

You can trigger the activation manually and look for an error there

```
pvscan -v -a ay /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2
```

I suppose you should also try the same things on `/dev/sdb` as well.

It doesn't look like you're missing any error messages though.  This implies that there is no attempt to activate the LVM partition...  (possibly it's not being identified as such because someone wiped the header...).  The log should really include some details if it had found anything with LVM e.g. (on Fedora, i.e. newer software):

```
Apr 15 15:59:52 localhost.localdomain dracut-initqueue[374]: Scanning devices sda3  for LVM logical volumes vg_fossil/root_2
Apr 15 15:59:52 localhost.localdomain dracut-initqueue[374]: File descriptor 98 (socket:[10072]) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 448: /
Apr 15 15:59:52 localhost.localdomain dracut-initqueue[374]: File descriptor 99 (socket:[10073]) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 448: /
Apr 15 15:59:52 localhost.localdomain dracut-initqueue[374]: inactive '/dev/vg_fossil/root' [10.00 GiB] inherit
Apr 15 15:59:52 localhost.localdomain dracut-initqueue[374]: inactive '/dev/vg_fossil/root_2' [92.00 GiB] inherit
Apr 15 15:59:52 localhost.localdomain dracut-initqueue[374]: inactive '/dev/vg_fossil/docker-pool' [5.34 GiB] inherit
Apr 15 15:59:52 localhost.localdomain dracut-initqueue[374]: File descriptor 98 (socket:[10072]) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 448: /
Apr 15 15:59:52 localhost.localdomain dracut-initqueue[374]: File descriptor 99 (socket:[10073]) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 448: /
Apr 15 15:59:52 localhost.localdomain dracut-initqueue[374]: /etc/lvm/profile/vg_fossil--docker-pool-extend.profile: stat failed: No such fi
Apr 15 15:59:52 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Found device /dev/mapper/vg_fossil-root_2.
```

You need to look at the commandline passed to the kernel and dracut initramfs.

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

because it's possible to pass options to dracut which tell it not to scan for LVM.

---

A second trick would be to scan for filesystems.  If your LVM LVs are contiguous - e.g. if you never enlarged them - then testdisk would give you access to all the data.  You can install and run testdisk if you boot into a decent rescue system.  For example, this would let you investigate the filesystems in sda2, even if someone had wiped the LVM PV header.